# How to bind an specific processor core to specific RAM DIMM

Tags: memory-management, binding

I would like to bind a specific processor core to a specific RAM DIMM.

Example:

CPU-> Intel i7 2600K (Quadcore) where each core is listed as 0,1,2,3
RAM-> 2 * 2GB DDR3 (Specifics not necessary) listed as 0,1

I would like to execute a program that runs on CPU core 2, and use only RAM DIMM 0.

The closest tool to use would be numactl, but numactl (as far as I have read) controls the memory of a node as a whole not per DIMM.

Your help would be much appreciated...

Comment: Wow, I'd be interested in the usecase for _that._

Comment: What possible reason would you have to do such a thing, very interested to know!